# PHP connection_aborted doesn't work with nginx?

Tags: php, nginx

I can't seem to get the function connection_aborted to work with nginx. The code I used to test is as follow:

```
<?php
ignore_user_abort(true);
ob_implicit_flush();
$i = 0;
while (!connection_aborted()) {
    echo $i;
    $i++;
    sleep(1);
}
file_put_contents('test',$i);
```

In Apache, it works correctly, although it delays a little. i.e. When I press stop button on browser when "3", the 'test' file shows "8". That is an acceptable margin, but on nginx, it doesn't seem to output anything to the 'test' file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your Nginx configuration, it should have

```
fastcgi_ignore_client_abort off;
```

This configuration key has `off` as the default, so even if you have no `fastcgi_ignore_client_abort` at all, your script should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that "connection_aborted()" is unable to detect the "ABORTED" connection
(and the script is **still running**)

Comment: That's also my guess, but I'm looking for a solution, unless you're telling me it's nginx's bug...