# Are requests canceled by a client passed through nginx to the fastcgi

Tags: nginx, go, fastcgi, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm using NGINX as a reverse proxy in conjunction with the `ngx_http_fastcgi_module`. It is proxying requests to a custom Golang FastCGI that executes a PHP-CGI process.

There are requests that take an excessive amount of time because of some complex code that our customers are using. If the User clicks a different link while waiting for the request the browser cancels the previous request and NGINX sees it:

```
[info] 24#24: *1516 client 1.2.3.4 closed keepalive connection
```

which is great! But my upstream PHP-CGI process continues to run until it times out. This can consume a lot of resources if the user continues to click more links. I suspect my problem might be that NGINX isn't explicitly cancelling the upstream request. I've found the setting [fastcgi_ignore_client_abort](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_ignore_client_abort) and it seems that by default it would *not* be ignored (which is good). It says:

> Determines whether the connection with a proxied server should be closed when a client closes the connection without waiting for a response.

Does that mean it's actually terminating the upstream request as well, or just ignoring the upstream request/response?

And if it *should* be sending a signal upstream, is there a way in NGINX that I can verify it is working as expected?

On the Fast-CGI side of things the Golang server is listening for a `Done()` from the `http.Request.Context()` while it executes the request. If NGINX is explicitly terminating the upstream request we think that should detect it. Does anyone know if that's incorrect?

Comment: Same situation discussed here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20251224/nginx-php-stop-process-at-canceled-request

Comment: @gammazero, Thanks that is useful information. But I think that answer is discussing the communication between the FCGI or FPM and the application code (or child process).

I think the break-down in our system is between NGINX and the Golang application which, in turn runs FCGI. I'll update my question to more accurately reflect our architecture.